# set permission in acl.ini in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

can someone guide me for setting permission in acl.ini in zend framework i have a specific type of user and i want to give permission to access particular controller. i have implemented Admin_MarketingController in admin section and include this controller in default module which name is also MarketingController  index action work properly but any action i want to access url sent to error page access Marketing controller in admin section it work properly.
plz help me to set permission and access other action 
include file path :APPLICATION_PATH/modules/admin/controllers/MarketingController.php
default controller MarketingController inherit with Admin_MarketingController